# How to downgrade React Devtools Chromium extension version?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

React Devtools extension no longer works in our app and I've ruled out basically everything except for a change in the version of the devtools themselves. Is there some way I can download older versions of the React Devtools extension? Either packed or unpacked would be very helpful to us.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app wrapped in Electron or similar? There is an issue on GitHub discussing a problem that may be of some help or at least give you some clues. React Dev Tools 4.25 used chrome manifest V2, and more recent versions use manifest V3 - a breaking change for technologies that rely on it and haven't yet addressed this change  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/25843 .